# Send key presses programmatically

Tags: android

I am editing csipsimple https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple&hl=en 
to add a push to talk button. When I dial *9 during a call(on the apps keyboard) I can push to talk. when I press #9 it turns off this mode. This all works manually.
I wrote a method in which these keys should be pressed in one button, so you dont have to popup the keyboard and press the codes every time. However the call mode is not changing, I do not know why. I tried the same thing in another sip app and it worked.
Anything wrong with this method?

Is there a different way to send the key presses (I dont even know if they are being sent, I dont know how I can tell, the app keyboard is offscreen as its a popup, but I can see that the button to bring up the keyboard is highlighted when I press my button to send keys)

```
public void pushtotalk3(final View view) {
        final boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(false);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                    if (on) {

                        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to send keycodes: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```